# Inequalities involving expectations

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Consider four random variables $W, X,Q,Y$, where $Q$ and $Y$ are binary. Assume
$$
\begin{aligned}
& (1) \quad E(Q(X+W)|Y=1)\geq 0\\
& (2) \quad E(W|Y=1)=0\\
& (3) \quad \Pr(Q=1|Y=1,W)=1
\end{aligned}
$$
Note that (2) and (3) imply
$$
(4) \quad E(QW|Y=1)=0
$$
Hence, by combining (1) and (4), we conclude
$$
(5) \quad E(QX|Y=1)\geq 0.
$$

**Question:** I want to obtain (5) under a condition weaker than (3), ideally, something like
$$
(3')\quad \Pr(Q=1|Y=1,W)> \Pr(Q=0|Y=1,W).
$$
To this end, I am willing to also modify (2), where I suspect we might need something like
$$
(2')\quad E(W|Y=1)\leq 0.
$$
I cannot modify (1).
If this strategy does not seem meaningful, could you advise on an alternative successful strategy? Also, I cannot assume mean independence between $W,Q$ or impose $E(W|Q=1)=0$.

Comment: What is the support of $W$? Is $W$ non-negative? Non-positive? Arbitrary? Can its various conditional supports be affected/restricted, or this should not/cannot happen?

Comment: $W$ is absolutely continuous, with support equal to the real line.

Comment: Its support conditions can be costrained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that all the $Y=1$ conditions can be dropped, as everything is conditioned on $Y=1$, and $Y$  appears nowhere except in the conditioning part of the statements.

Replacement condition:

(2'). $E(W|Q=1)=0$

This will do the job as a weaker replacement for (2) and (3) together, as a) $E(QW|Q=0) =0$ by construction and b) $Q$ binary together with (2') imply (4), which, as you observe, combined with (1) implies (5).

Note that (2') is a *necessary* condition for (4) to hold, as

$$E(QW) = 0\cdot p(Q=0) + E(W|Q=1)\cdot p(Q=1)$$

so for $E(QW) = 0$, it must be that $E(W|Q=1) = 0$ or $p(Q=1)=0$, the latter of which simplifies the problem considerably!

This assumption is much weaker than the original (2) and (3); it makes no assumption about $p(Q=1)$, as does (3), and it does not assume the existence of moments for $W$, as does (2), except when $Q=1$.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot assume mean independence between $W,Q$

Comment: Apologies for not having specified this!!!

Comment: 1) I am not assuming mean independence between $W$ and $Q$.  2) Note that whatever conditions you impose, they have to end up with $E(W|Q=1) = 0$, as $E(WQ) = 0\cdot p(Q=0) + E(W|Q=1)\cdot p(Q=1)$, so, for $E(WQ) = 0$, it must be that $E(W|Q=1) = 0$ or $p(Q=0) = 1$.

Comment: Ok, understood.

Answer (score 4):

We must have that $W$ and $Q$ are not mean-independent, so they are certainly statistically dependent.

But *conditional* independence does not imply, nor is implied by, independence.

**Assume** then conditional independence of $Q$ from $W$ given $Y=1$:
$$A1: \Pr(Q \mid Y=1, W) = \Pr(Q \mid Y=1)$$

From the linearity of expected value we have
$$(1):\; E(Q(X+W)|Y=1)= E(QX|Y=1) + E(QW|Y=1) \geq 0$$
$$\implies E(QX|Y=1) \geq -E(QW|Y=1).$$

So a **sufficient** condition for what we want is
$$E(QW|Y=1) \leq 0.$$

Under $A1$,

$$E(QW|Y=1)  = E(Q|Y=1) \cdot E(W|Y=1) = E(Q|Y=1) \cdot 0 = 0.$$

Whether the $A1$ assumption is considered a "weaker" assumption than OP's eq. $(3)$,  depends on the particulars of the case.

**ADDENDUM**

In a later comment the OP informed that the conditional supports can be different than the unconditional ones. In such a case:

We need only to assume $(1)$ and

$$A2: W \mid \{Y=1\}\, \in (-\infty, 0]. $$

From $(1)$ we still get that a sufficient condition for what we want is $E(QW|Y=1) \leq 0$. Since $Q \in \{0,1\}$ and since, under $\{Y=1\}$, $W$ is non-positive, it follows that
$$QW \mid \{Y=1\} \leq 0 \implies E(QW|Y=1) \leq 0$$

$$\implies E(QX|Y=1) \geq 0.$$